# Calling two function alternatively on clicking the same element

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call two function alternatively on clicking the same element in which I need to call one function with parameter and the other without parameter. It is basically that I need to select the element on first click and unselect on the second click. 
My JS code:

```
    var list = document.getElementById("sectionDispName");

            for (var i = 0; i < secArr.length ; i++) {
                list.innerHTML += '<li onclick="func(this)"    ondblclick="dblclickadd(this)"> ' + secArr[i][0] + '</li> ';

            } 
var func = (function (val) {

       var first = true;
       return function (val) { // argument moved to here.

           first ? getValue(val) : singleclick();
           first = !first;
        }
   })();
```

getValue(val) function is for selecting the element and singleclick() is for unselecting.

Comment: Does it work?  Is there a problem?

Comment: Declare **var first = true;**  outside of function should work.

Comment: try @NullPointer 's solution, it should work, if that's your problem

Comment: okay, also when I am adding an alert( val) in the func() , the value of val is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but something like this makes sense to me and is a little simpler:

```
var list = document.getElementById("sectionDispName");

var selected = [];
for (var i = 0; i < secArr.length ; i++) {
    selected.push(false);
    list.innerHTML +=
        '<li onclick="toggleSelected(' + i + ')" ondblclick="dblclickadd(this)">' +
        secArr[i][0] + '</li>';
}

var toggleSelected = function(i) {
    selected[i] = !selected[i];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> When you call a function, amongst other things a "variable
>   environment" for that call is created, which has something called a
>   "binding object". (Call it the "variable object" for short; saying
>   "the binding object of the variable environment" is just a tad bit
>   long-winded!) The variable object has properties for the arguments to
>   the function, all local variables declared in the function, and all
>   functions declared within the function are alive only inside the
>   fucntion.

This mean when you used

```
 var func = (function (val) {

    var first = true;
    /* Code */
 }
```

That is also what is known as **variable scope**.

A variable only exists within its containing function/method/class, and those will override any variables which belong to a wider scope.

The `var first` was stored only when the function is excuted after that it would be destroyed. then you need a global variable to store that data :

```
var first = true;
var func = (function (val) {
/* Code */
}
```

or

```
var first = [];
var func = (function (val) {
first.push(true);
/* Code */
}
```

Comment: I applied all the solution given above but the problem is still . I am selecting and at the same time it is getting unselected. Even now my ondblclick event is not working. Please help me.

Comment: @Neha can you edit your question with your lastest code

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain about your approach because there are better means. But still, you have misunderstood the behavior here. You have written

```
var func = (function (val) {
    var first = true;
    return function () {
        first ? getValue(val) :singleclick();
        first = !first;
    }
})();
```

which is an IIFE. However, `func` holds the function that you have returned. That `return function () {...}`. That function does not expect an argument. Yet you attempt to call that function *with* an argument.

If you want to pass an argument, please move the argument from the IIFE initializer to your returning function object. So, do `return function (val) {...}`. In this situation, `func` is now a function object with one argument.

Here below is an interactive example. I have adjusted some values for PoC purpose. Just click on the list element.

```js
var func = (function() {
  var first = true;
  return function(val) { // argument moved to here.
    console.log('first? ' + first);
    first ? getValue(val) : singleclick();
    first = !first;
  }
})();

function getValue(val){
  console.log('getValue called with ' + val);
}
function singleclick(){
  console.log('singleclick called');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li onclick="func(1)">list 1</li>
  <li onclick="func(2)">list 2</li>
  <li onclick="func(3)">list 3</li>
  <li onclick="func(4)">list 4</li>
  <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You weren't passing val to returned function.

```js
var func = (function (val) {
    var first = true;
    return function (val) {
        first = !first;
        first ? getValue(val) : singleclick();
    }
})();
window.onload = function () {
    var list = document.getElementById("sectionDispName");

    for (var i = 0; i < secArr.length; i++) {
        list.innerHTML += '<li onclick="func(this)"  ondblclick="dblclickadd(this)"> ' + secArr[i][0] +
            '</li> ';
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
        var secArr = [
            ['element_0_0'],
            ['element_1_0'],
            ['element_2_0'],
            ['element_3_0']
        ];

        function getValue(HTMLelement) {
            console.log('getValue',
                HTMLelement);
        }

        function singleclick() {
            console.log('singleclick');
        }
    </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <ol id="sectionDispName"></ol>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For multiple selection, if I am selecting one element and clicking on the other element to select the first element got unselected.